# Extracting XML Attributes in Java(ISBNDB)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

So I'm writing an android app that needs to grab book price data from the web. I found isbndb.com which seems to provide good reasourses and price comparison. The only issue is that their xml files are a bit complex.

I am new to parsing XML in Java and don't know too much. I know how to parse basic xml files. With simple tags. I usually use the DocumentBuilder and the DocumentBuilderFactory However this is the part of the file which I'm trying to parse.

```
<Prices price_time="2012-04-08T20:05:49Z">
<Price store_isbn="" store_title="Discworld: Thief of Time" store_url="http://isbndb.com/x/book/thief_of_time/buy/isbn/ebay.html" store_id="ebay" currency_code="USD" is_in_stock="1" is_historic="0" check_time="2008-12-09T12:00:51Z" is_new="0" currency_rate="1" price="0.99"/>
<Price store_isbn="" store_title="" store_url="http://bookshop.blackwell.com/bobus/scripts/home.jsp?action=search&type=isbn&term=0061031321&source=1154376025" store_id="blackwell" currency_code="USD" is_in_stock="0" is_historic="0" is_new="1" check_time="2011-11-08T02:54:15Z" currency_rate="1" price="7.99"/> 
</Prices>
```

What I am trying to do is grab the info in the attribute values such as store_isbn or store_title. If anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything? http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Comment: I completed a tutorial just like that and I understand how it works. However that example doesn't include any of the attribute tags which I'm trying to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the above mentioned [link](http://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser) for parsing xml and For retrieving the attribute values you can use following.

```
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    System.out.println("Start Element :" + attributes.getValue("store_title"));




}
```

attributes.getValue("store_title") method will be used for parsing attribute values. Hope it will help.